# How to plot a scatterplot and label points using a text column in Tikz Pgf

Tags: latex, pgfplots

I want to plot a scatter plot and label points using text picked from the table which I paste from notepad.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
x   y   label  
23  9.6 Jan
46  11.3 Feb
60  12.8 Mar
54  9.8 Apr
}\advdata

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\caption{Scatterplot of Advertising versus Sales Data}
\vspace*{15mm}
\scalebox{1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {Advertising (x)}, ylabel = {Sales (y)}
]
\addplot[
mark=*,only marks,
point meta =explicit symbolic,
nodes near coords* = {\label},
]
table[x=x,y=y, meta =label]{\advdata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get this error: ! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'Jan' as a floating point numbe
r, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'Jan'..

How can I make this thing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just `nodes near coords`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
x   y   label
23  9.6 Jan
46  11.3 Feb
60  12.8 Mar
54  9.8 Apr
}\advdata

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Scatterplot of Advertising versus Sales Data}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {Advertising (x)}, ylabel = {Sales (y)}
]
\addplot[
mark=*,only marks,
point meta =explicit symbolic,
nodes near coords,
]
table[x=x,y=y, meta =label]{\advdata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]